# I can't uninstall the existing service worker

Tags: angular6, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I have created basic sample application and integrated angular/pwa. In ngsw-config .json file i added datagroups for api call. Now i can able to download the application and api call is working fine in offline too.
After that i moved to my application and did the same for pwa. Now api call is not working in offline. I checked with api call which i used in sample application still i'm getting the data for that url but i didn't specified in ngsw-config.json file.

I can't unregistered my old service worker and create new service worker. In chrome developer tool i unregistered that service worker and again reload my application but still i'm getting the old data.

Angular version: 6.0.2

Browser:
- [ ] Chrome (desktop) version

For Tooling issues:
- Node version: 8.9.1
- Platform:  Windows

Comment: Hi, I was able to get PWA up & running on Angular 5... but ran into issues in Angular 6... now that i tried PWA again on Angular 7, the experience was smooth, you may want to try this now;